# How to choose between similar answers?

Tags: discussion, opinion-based

I have gotten some good answers on a question of mine, wherein the lot can be classified into 2 broad groups of recommendations.

There is a majority of answers that recommend one approach but all with different tonalities and arguments as to why.

I am inclined to accept one of them, but that answer recommends the same path as some of the earlier answers, the only difference being how they have addressed the question exactly. Essentially this answer made me see clearly as to why the argument is valid.

---

> Example
>
> 1. Do **A** because `X`, `Y`
> 2. Do **A** because `P`, `S`
>
> Both recommend doing **A**, but `P` and `S` helped me see the merit behind `X` and `Y`

---

In such a scenario, what should be my best course of action?

1. Accept the first answer that recommended the path
2. Accept the answer that helped me see the merit behind the first answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The one that you found most helpful or valuable in helping you to resolve your issue.

You don't really need to justify why you chose one answer over another unless you really want to.

It can happen that a combination of different points of view leads to a resolution, but unfortunately, you can only pick one answer.